# Suppress right click on Leaflet.js popup

Tags: popup, leaflet, right-click

I have tried the following code to suppress the default right click on a Leaflet popup:

> $('.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper').bind('contextmenu', function(e)
>   {
>         return false;   });

This technique works fine on all other classes but not in this instance.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "suppresing" an event. You can *stop propagation* of an event, and *prevent the default action* of an event, but *supressing* an event is not a thing.

Do read:

http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#domevent-stoppropagation

http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#domevent-preventdefault

http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#domevent-stop

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

[event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false#1357151)

Do you want to stop the event from bubbling? Do you want to prevent the browser from displaying the right-click menu? Both?

Also note that jQuery events are **not** DOM events, and furthermore, Leaflet events are **not** DOM events. Stopping a jQuery/Leaflet event might not stop the underlying DOM event under some circumstances. Using [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) or some super-simple wrapper as `L.DomEvent.on()` helps to regain control in these cases.

Comment: Ookay, that gives me something to work on. Many thanks.