# How to disable events on the popup tip with leaflet 1.7.1

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I display a marker on a map with a popup window in which an image is displayed with a hyperlink.
When the mouse in on the tip, an hand is displayed (why ?) and if I click then the popup is closed !?

I added in my css the disable of the events on the tip but that seems to not be the solution.

```
var options = {
   'className': 'custom-popup'
}
popup = "<a href='" + (BASE_URL || '') + m.link + "'>" + "<img src='" +  (BASE_URL || '') + m.image + "' /></a>"; 
marker.bindPopup(popup,options).openPopup();
```

The css custom-popup supersedes the leaflet.css:

```
.custom-popup div.leaflet-popup-content {
  min-Width: 300px;
  max-Width: 300px;
  max-Height: 500px;
}
.custom-popup .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
  background:#2c3e50;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:24px;
}
.custom-popup .leaflet-popup-tip-container {
  width:40px;
  height:20px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.custom-popup .leaflet-popup-tip {
  background:#2c3e50;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the mouse in on the tip, an hand is displayed (why ?) and if I click then the popup is closed !?

Precisely because `pointer-events: none` is the default for `.leaflet-popup-tip-container`. The tip does *not* trigger events, so when a user clicks on the tip, the click goes *straight through* to the underlying element (the Leaflet map), which does trigger events. Then, the default behaviour when clicking on the map itself is to close the active popup.

Also related: [There is no such thing as "disabling" events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044016/suppress-right-click-on-leaflet-js-popup/43046977#43046977) and [parts of a Leaflet popup](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285588/why-does-the-classname-option-of-a-leaflet-popup-change-only-the-outside-of-the/285662#285662).

The approach here would be to apply the CSS rule `pointer-events: auto` or `pointer-events: initial` to `.leaflet-popup-tip`. Pointer interactions on the tip *shall* trigger DOM events that are not listened to and therefore *do nothing*.

Comment: OK !!! what is the difference between auto and initial ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the popup directly to marker, create a popup "layer" and open it, when clicked on the marker:

```
// a global variable
var popup = L.popup({'className': 'custom-popup', closeOnClick: false, autoClose: false, closeButton: true});

function openPopup(e){
    var marker = e.target;
    popup.options.offset = marker.options.icon.options.popupAnchor;
    popup.setContent(marker._popupContentTemp).setLatLng(marker.getLatLng()).addTo(map)
}


//your marker creation with click event
marker = new L.marker(latlng).addTo(lmap);
marker.on('click',openPopup, this)
marker._popupContentTemp = "<a href='" + (BASE_URL || '') + m.link + "'>" + "<img src='" +  (BASE_URL || '') + m.image + "' /></a>";
```

Now the popup is opened with the custom content and can't closed by clicking on the marker